# pass weightmap to loss function in Keras : y_true shape problem

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, loss

It's my first time asking question in this platform, apology to that if my english is not good to express accurately.
It's about implementing loss function with weightmap in semantic segmentation. I've searched a lot online and tried, I think this solution seems reasonable: merge the mask(y_train) and weightmap (pre-calculated based on mask) into one matrix as the input of y in model.fit() and did some test.
However,the shape of y_true is strange in training. Here is the example, the version of tensorflow is 2.8.2 and keras is 2.8.0:

data:

> ```
> shape of x_train(images):(240,256,256,1) numpy 
> shape of y_train(masks):(240,256,256,1)  numpy  
> shape of weightmap:(240,256,256,1)       numpy  
> shape of new_y_train(merged y_train and weightmap):(240,256,256,2)  tensor
> ```

(not sure whether the type of new_y_train affects or not,but after converting it to numpy type still got the same problem)

Here is the model and training setting,I use FCN to test:

```
def weighted_fcn(n=32):

        input_shape = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))

        x = Conv2D(n, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_shape)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

        x = Conv2D(n*2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

        x = Conv2D(n*4, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

        x = Conv2D(n*8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

        x = Conv2D(n*16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

        x = Dense(n*16, activation='relu')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D(size=2)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
        x = Conv2D(n*8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D(size=2)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
        x = Conv2D(n*4, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D(size=2)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
        x = Conv2D(n*2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D(size=2)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
        x = Conv2D(n, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D(size=2)(x)
        outputs = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

        model = Model(inputs=input_shape, outputs=outputs)
      
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=[custom_loss_wrapper2], metrics=[custom_binary_accuracy])

        return model

# training

model = weighted_fcn()

history3 = model.fit(x=x_train,y=new_y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=50, batch_size=16, callbacks=callbacks)
```

the custom loss function and custom accuracy((I use many print in loss function to check shape, keep them to match the output):

```
def custom_loss_wrapper2(y_true, y_pred):

    print('y_true_shape',y_true.shape)
    print('y_pred_shape',y_pred.shape)

    [target, weight] = tf.unstack(y_true, 2, axis=-1)

    print('target_shape,3 dims:',target.shape)
    print('weight_shape,3 dims:',weight.shape)

    target = tf.expand_dims(target, -1)
    weight = tf.expand_dims(weight, -1)

    print('target_shape,4 dims:',target.shape)
    print('weight_shape,4 dims:',weight.shape)

    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = (1 - target) * K.log(1 - y_pred + K.epsilon())  
    term_1 = target * K.log(y_pred + K.epsilon()) 

    res = -K.mean(weight*(term_0 + term_1), axis=-1)
    print('final_shape:',res.shape)
    return res

def custom_binary_accuracy(y_true,y_pred): 
    target,_= tf.unstack(y_true, 2, axis=-1)
    target=tf.expand_dims(target,-1)
    return K.mean(K.equal(target,K.round(y_pred)))
```

And last is the output and error:

```
Epoch 1/50
y_true_shape (16, 256, 256, 2)
y_pred_shape (16, 256, 256, 1)
target_shape,3 dims: (16, 256, 256)
weight_shape,3 dims: (16, 256, 256)
target_shape,4 dims: (16, 256, 256, 1)
weight_shape,4 dims: (16, 256, 256, 1)
final_shape: (16, 256, 256)
y_true_shape (16, 256, 256, 2)
y_pred_shape (16, 256, 256, 1)
target_shape,3 dims: (16, 256, 256)
weight_shape,3 dims: (16, 256, 256)
target_shape,4 dims: (16, 256, 256, 1)
weight_shape,4 dims: (16, 256, 256, 1)
final_shape: (16, 256, 256)
15/15 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6713 - custom_binary_accuracy: 0.6511y_true_shape (None, 256, 256, 1)
y_pred_shape (None, 256, 256, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ebe10f7660ba> in <module>()
      1 model = weighted_fcn()
      2 
----> 3 history3 = model.fit(x=x_train,y=new_y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=50, batch_size=16, callbacks=callbacks)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1525, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "<ipython-input-30-7faae313e7d4>", line 5, in custom_loss_wrapper2  *
        [target, weight] = tf.unstack(y_true, 2, axis=-1)

    ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 1 for '{{node custom_loss_wrapper2/unstack}} = Unpack[T=DT_FLOAT, axis=-1, num=2](IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,256,256,1].
```

what i expect is that input y has shape (240,256,256,2) and in training the custom loss fucntion should receive y_true as (batch_size,256,256,2), then i can split it into two  (batch_size,256,256) and convert it to (batch_size,256,256,1).

but it seems that y_true become (None,256,256,1) as input to loss function? which is really strange.
And i don't know why in the beginning the outputs gave the right information and it then gave a different y_true shape. (I'm not clear of the details about how model.fit() calls the loss function, these information makes me really confused and i want to know how to pass the weightmap in a correct way)

Is there any suggestion or solution to this?